# How to accept any file type by <input type="file"> without HTML validity violations?

Tags: html

I have not found the examples how to accept any file type by `<input type="file">`.

When I tried `accept="*/*"`, I has been told

> Bad value “*/*” for attribute “accept” on element “input”: Expected “/” but saw “*” instead."

by the HTML validator.

When I tried `accept=""`, I has been told

> Bad value “” for attribute “accept” on element “input”: Expected a MIME type but the literal ended."

by the HTML validator.

When I tried `accept="*"`, I has been told

> Bad value “*” for attribute “accept” on element “input”: Expected “/” but saw “*” instead."

by the HTML validator.

### Why are you going to accept any type of files? Usually only one type of files required.

For example it is requires when developing the online files storage like the Google Drive.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `accept` attribute?

Comment: `<input type="file">` should be sufficient to allow any file type. You don't need to whitelist everything, it's the default.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Thank you for the comment. You right, looks like the HTML validator does not complain. Please write the answer if you want reputation points reputation by be accepted & upvoted.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, Thank you for the comment. You right, looks like the HTML validator does not complain. Please write the answer if you want reputation points reputation by be accepted & upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[List of all the official MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

If you really want to use `accept` attribute:

```html
<input
  type="file"
  accept="
    application/*,
    audio/*,
    font/*,
    example/*,
    image/*,
    message/*,
    model/*,
    multipart/*,
    text/*,
    video/*
  "
>
```

Or just remove `accept` attribute :

```html
<input type="file">
```